# How is an image created by a PHP script?

Tags: php, html, image

I was looking at an possibly fraudulent eBay auction. However I am confused by an image within it, since it does not appear to be an image.

> youneedtobuy.intothis.org/win.php

The complete HTML content of the url above is:

```
<body>
<img src="http://youneedtobuy.intothis.org/win.php" >
</body>
```

[image]

Here is a screen copy of the image, with the email address blurred out by me. There is no JS scripting, no CSS to speak of, just one line of code.

So, essentially the scammer can insert an 'image' into their eBay ad, and that image won't be scanned by normal tools.

How is this image created? And how could the friendly folks at ebay include a scanner in their system that has the ability to "see" this image (and preclude the scam from re-occurring?)

Comment: In what way is that not an image? Looks like an image to me. Do you mean that it has a `.php` extension?

Comment: @halfer I think he means that it doesn't have a common image extension.

Comment: The URL or better the php file returns an image. That's all - in php you can read a files (image) content and echo it out. With the right headers you see an image in your browser.

Comment: PHP has a built-in GD library which you can use for dynamic image creation. When you visit the website, it sends a `GET` request to the PHP script, which then generates the image and it is then displayed on the page. That's all.

Comment: Assuming this is a scam, eBay could blacklist the URL of the image, or perhaps a hash of the image file, to prevent it working on new domains. But there is nothing inherently wrong with serving images this way, it is quite common.

Comment: A file extension has not much to do with the file type (unless you are on a Windows machine…).

Comment: In the meantime, the 'designer' of that image should be arrested for crimes against exclamation marks.

Comment: *The complete HTML content of the url above is* -  There is no HTML content, it's pure image/binary content. The HTML you see is generated by your browser because an image does not have a *sourcecode* to view.

Comment: You think exclamation marks are funny. check out the grammar @ the auction site:  http://www.ebay.com/itm/121341059058  Note: that welder price should be around $4K or so...

Comment: Addition: Generally, if an auction is trying to convince you to "change the way a normal ebay auction works", especially when leading to a 3rd party website, **report it to ebay and do not bid**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is likely created using PHP's `file_get_contents()` function. For example, the following PHP script will display the contents of `myimage.jpg` to the browser, but the file could be called `show-image.php`:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: ".(string)(filesize('myimage.jpg')));

echo file_get_contents('myimage.jpg');
?>
```

As you can see, this is achieved by telling PHP to serve up the `image/jpeg` MIME type.

Comment: Yep, although the string casting is implicit, since the concatenation forces it anyway.

Comment: I just verified that file_get_contents produces exactly that result, with the accompanying css that I see on the spammers site.    The other half of the question.  Can ebay scan this "image" if they wanted to and see the contents of the image?

Comment: @zipzit eBay can scan it, yes, as per my comment under the question. They could use hashing, but good luck in getting in touch with an eBay technical expert to talk about it!

Comment: Yes, they could. It arrives as a JPEG image, so could be easily hashed.

Comment: I'm not suggesting Ebay would ever do that.  There are times they don't seem quite so customer focused, sigh. e.g. How hard is it to change the local display time zone for an auction end? (or is the whole world on pacific time?)

Answer (score 1):

Any image can be returned by a script instead of a real file.

An alternative answer shows methods of doing this, but by using a script one can serve different images to different users, log IP address and other information thus tracking viewers etc.

It is also a common technique used to return thumbnail or summary images. e.g. using PHP and ImageMagick to generate an image of the first page of a PDF file.

Incidentally the image **will** be scanned by normal tools - they simply look for the image tags, not what extension the file has. What you are really saying is that the text contained within the image won't be processed or analysed, and the image does invite you to directly connect to someone, which is against eBays terms and conditions.